# How do I configure heroku psql database using .sh files?

Tags: node.js, heroku, psql, heroku-postgres

I have a web app hosted on heroku and I am trying to set up my database by using the same script I have used in offline testing, but on heroku I am not sure how to run my .sh script:

```
dropdb -U node_user mydb
createdb -U node_user mydb

psql -U node_user mydb < ./bin/sql/firsttable.sql
psql -U node_user mydb < ./bin/sql/secondtable.sql
psql -U node_user mydb < ./bin/sql/thridtable.sql
```

each of the .sql files include sql commands such as:

```
CREATE TABLE firsttable(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(64),
    user VARCHAR(64),
    date TIMESTAMP
);
```

How do I run my .sh script on heroku's psql so that all of the tables are created?

Answer (score 1):

Run them from your machine using your local psql by connecting to the DB on Heroku.

For that you just need the credentials, which you can obtain with this:

```
$ heroku pg:credentials:url
```

Note that you will not be able to drop and create databases on Heroku with `dropdb` and `createdb`.

For the SQL files, you can run them as follows:

```
$ psql $(heroku pg:credentials:url | grep 'postgres://') -f local_file.sql
```

Comment: ...but you won't be able to `dropdb` or `createdb`. Use [`heroku pg:reset`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset) instead, if you need to.